# Markov Decision Process

Tags: probability, markov-process

Consider a Markov decision process $(S, A, P, R)$ where $S=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is a state space, $A=$ $\left\{a^{1}, a^{2}\right\}$ is an action space, $P$ is a transition probability matrix such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P\left((s+1) \% 5 \mid s, a^{1}\right)=P\left((s+2) \% 5 \mid s, a^{1}\right)=P\left((s+4) \% 5 \mid s, a^{1}\right)=\frac{1}{3} \\
&P\left((s+1) \% 5 \mid s, a^{2}\right)=P\left((s+3) \% 5 \mid s, a^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
(where $a \% b$ means the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$ ) for all $s \in S$ and $R$ is the reward such that $R\left(s, a, s^{\prime}\right)$ follows Bernoulli $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ if $s^{\prime}=0$ and $0$ otherwise. Also, when the process reaches the state $4$, then the process is terminated (i.e. $4$ is the terminal state). Assume the initial state is $s_{0}=0$ and set the discounted factor $\gamma=0.9.$ Let $\pi$ be a Markovian randomized stationary policy that $\pi\left(a^{1} \mid s\right)=\pi\left(a^{2} \mid s\right)=$ $0.5$ for $s=0,2$ and $\pi\left(a^{1} \mid s\right)=0.7, \pi\left(a^{2} \mid s\right)=0.3$ for $s=1,3.$ In this problem, you may use the python code for matrix calculations, e.g. matrix addition, multiplication, inversion, $\ldots$

Considering these given statements, how can we calculate $V^{\pi}(s)$ and $Q^{\pi}(s, a)$?

Having gone through multiple ideas for MDP, it seemed somewhat confusing how one could tackle the problem theoretically when we adopt the policy $\pi$, especially the evaluation of probabilities that trajectory is sampled. It could be great if anyone could share some insights on the calculation of it.

Comment: Any ideas that are insightful could be really appreciative!

Comment: You can use the Bellman Equation iteratively starting with a value function zero everywhere. This method converges usually very quickly.

But since you have a very small state and action space the Bellman Equation is only a small set of linear equations that you can write down explicitly. You then solve this using matrix methods (simple linear algebra).

Comment: Thank you @PeterKeller for your comment, appreciate it! If possible, could you please assist in providing those sets of linear equations in more detail, since after some trials using the Bellman Equation iteratively, I could not finalize correctly all of these matrix calculations? It could be really appreciative if more detailed relations would be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bellman equation for this problem is given as a system of $|S|$ equations:

$$V^\pi(s)=\sum_{actions\ a}\pi(a|s)\sum_{states\ s'}P(s'|s,a)(R(s',a,s)+\gamma\cdot V^\pi(s'))$$

The trick is to rewrite this in matrix form:
$$V^\pi=\pi^1 P_1( R_1\mathbf 1^\top+\gamma  V^\pi)+\pi^2 P_2( R_2\mathbf 1^\top+\gamma  V^\pi)$$

where $$\pi^i=(\pi(a^i|0),\ldots,\pi(a^i|4))$$
$$R_i=\begin{pmatrix}
R(0,a^i,0)&\ldots &R(4,a^i,0)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
R(0,a^i,4)&\ldots& R(4,a^i,4)
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf 1=(1,\ldots,1)$$

Then, you can regroup and get
$$V^\pi=(\pi^1P_1R_1+\pi^2P_2R_2)\mathbf1^\top+(\pi^1P_1+\pi^2P_2)V^\pi$$

Which finally results in
$$V^\pi=(Id-\gamma(\pi^1P_1+\pi^2P_2))^{-1}(\pi^1P_1R_1+\pi^2P_2R_2)\mathbf1^\top$$
The inverse exists only for $\gamma<1$.
Please check this carefully. The formula is a lot more complicated than what you find in the literature, as the rewards are randomized and depend on state transition, too.

If you like to check, whether your computations are correct, try to implement the recursion with initially $V^\pi(0)=(0,0,0,0,0)$ and
$$V^\pi(k+1,s)\leftarrow\sum_{actions\ a}\pi(a|s)\sum_{states\ s'}P(s'|s,a)(R(s',a,s)+\gamma\cdot V^\pi(k,s'))$$

No guarantee for correctness here. I am almost sure I made some mistake and could have written some of it more elegantly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter for such comprehensive feedback on this problem, glad for your assistance! I was wondering where exactly errors could occur? It seems a little bit computationally wrong, but not sure where exactly from your perspective

Comment: Could you please point out or maybe modify accordingly if possible?

Comment: I am almost sure it works as written. But I couldn't find references in the literature to this formula for the matrix version. So, please try if that works. Errors could be in the dimensions of the matrices and maybe I transposed something by accident. But the final expression seems right, as it has a similar form as the expression for non-random rewards that you find in the literature.